# Html add links to image

Tags: php, html

My code is below. I wanna add to link my website icon to the main page but its seems like it doesn't work.

```
$output .= " <img id='svg_logo' href='https://example.com/' src='https://example.com/path/' /> ";
```

Comment: If you want to link something, use a `<a>`

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<img>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-img-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Answer (score 6):

Because [an `<img>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img) *has no* `href` attribute.  You can't make something a "link" just by adding an `href` to it.

The `<img>` is the *content* of your "link", and the link itself is [a standard `<a>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a):

```
<a href="https://example.com/">
  <img id="svg_logo" src="https://example.com/path/" />
</a>
```

Comment: Note that the [<img>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-img-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.